# Can I bring together multiple Sharepoints (set & controlled by others) for easy access?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

This might not be the right website...but...please see if you can help me....

I work for a large corporation (100,000 employees).  In my role as mid-manager I have several everyday; MANY of the tasks require me accessing different SharePoints (about 12 different SharePoints).

Here is my question:  Is there such a thing as a SharePoint for SharePoints?  Is there a way for me to create a "library" of the SharePoints I need for quick access?  Every SharePoint has its purpose.  The problem is that the people who create SharePoints are focused on their purpose, not always realizing that many users has multiple other SharePoints they need to access.

Can I create a library or quick access for all the SharePoints I access and often times need to submit information on???  Is there a way to create a SharePoint that will link me to all the SharePoints I have to access?

Answer (score 0):

To literally answer your question, if you add the 'Link to a Document' content type to a library, you can add links to other sharepoint sites to a library.  here's a good how-to:

http://erichanes2008.blogspot.com/2011/05/adding-document-links-shortcuts-to.html

That may be overkill, you could probably just create a new link list like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMTI4sydm-c